# Need to Get Data from a table which contains unique id with different category in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

My Table Structure is:

artist_id     category

1                Song

1                Song

1                Song

1                Video

1                Video

Now, my output must be

id    category    total

1      Song         3

1      Video        2

How this can done by using MYSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work (untested):

```
select artist_id, category, count(*) as total from table group by artist_id, category
```